# UnavailableServiceException on lookup for "javax.jnlp.BasicService"

Tags: java, eclipse, jnlp, java-web-start

`UnavailableServiceException` is being thrown on look-up for `javax.jnlp.BasicService`.

Below is the code snippet:

```
BasicService basicServiceHandle = 
    (BasicService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
```

I am just trying an example of jnlp API - BasicService @ http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs as a Java Application.

Any suggestions as to what could be the reason for the same... or anything that could be worth checking?

### Update

I am not sure how I should be trying it from eclipse.

Comment: 1)  What is the content of the JNLP file used to launch the app.?  You might want to check/correct it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) before (further testing and) adding it as an edit to the question.  2) How is the app. being launched when it fails like that?  (Details, please.)

Comment: I am new to jnlp... I am just trying out the demo on BasicServise @ http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs as a Java Application...

Comment: Oh so *that* demo. is not working on your PC?  What OS/Java version etc. is installed on that machine?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by *"as a Java Application."*  Is that some choice in your IDE?  If so, note that the JNLP API is ***only available*** to apps. launched using a JNLP via. Java Web Start.  An IDE would typically **not** call that a 'Java application'.

Comment: The demo works great..! I have problem only when I download the code for the demo from the site and test it out as a Java Application in eclipse..

Comment: Oh ok... then I am not sure how I should be trying it from eclipse...

Comment: @AndrewThompson: is it possible to launch the application from Eclipse ***and*** include the JNLP API?

Comment: @Bicou  Do the instructions below not work for you?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Eclipse complains when I try to call `ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.SingleInstanceService")`, which is not exactly what's in this question, but related though.

Answer (score 1):

> ..not sure how I should be trying it from eclipse

- File|New|Java Project
- Project name: `BasicService`|Finish
- File|Import
- General|Archive File|Next
- From archive file: `basicservice.zip` (Into folder: `BasicService`)|Finish
- In the 'Package Explorer', navigate to: `BasiceService/basicservice/build.xml`
- Ctrl+F11 (Run)
- Ant Build|OK
- (Follow the prompts)

There may be better ways.  That as shown is just what I figured out from having downloaded Eclipse and doing a bit of a crash/bang through the help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info... I tried this out... exactly the same way as has been described... but I get "Application Error: Unable to launch the application."

Comment: ..and it also says something like **Click here for details**!

Comment: yes.. it does.. Its a "JNLParseException: Could not parse launch file. Error at line 1"